# degree of determinant line bundle of pullback in terms of Chern class

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I have a holomorphic map $f: C \to X$ where $\dim_\mathbb{C}C=1$ and $\dim_\mathbb{C}X=2$. Why is $\text{deg}\det f^*TX=-c_1(X)\cdot[C]$? I'm really curious to how that negative sign shows up.

Comment: The first Chern class of $X$ is the first Chern class of $-K_X$. The first thing you write is the pull back of the anticanonical class, and since the first Chern class on a curve is just the degree, your equation follows.